# How do you develop global wind patterns for your world?

Tags: science-based, climate, atmosphere, weather, wind

I'm trying to develop climatic maps for our countries and know that wind is a huge part of that. Our world is shaped the same as Earth, it's just a little smaller, and our axis is slightly less tilted (about a 20 degree tilt) so we have less dramatic variations in climate and season. Here's a draft of prevailing wind patterns, does it check out? I just sort of looked at the Earth's and followed patterns but had no actual scientific method other than making sure wind turned in the right direction based off of hemisphere. Is there a method? Do I need to come up with specific pressure cells? Thanks.
For reference:
-Vitya: 7.86 mil mi2
-Eios: 2.97 mil mi2
-Amari: 3.02 mil mi2
-Sabriel: 1.53 mil mi2
-Noor: 22,000 mi2

[image: map of global wind patterns picture]

Comment: How big are these islands?  Are they continents?

Comment: *Maybe* you could get something by looking at Earth's wind patterns, especially the seasonal variation. Off hand, those loops are a little concerning. And the two arrows at the bottom of the largest land mass going opposite right next to each other are pretty weird. You would need something to drive those if they were persistent.

Comment: @Willk Vitya: 7.86 million mi squared, Eios: 2.97 mil mi squared, Amari: 3.02 mil mil squared, Sabriel 1.53 mil mi squared, and Noor is 22,000 mi squared.

Comment: @puppetsock yeah, I'm clearly lost. Other than the bottom weird arrows, what makes them concerning? The amount, size, spacing, positions?

Comment: How complicated do you want to get?  At the extreme, run a general circulation model that's designed for exoplanets, for instance https://github.com/exoclime/THOR

Comment: What level of plausibility is desired? If you just want it to not be plainly stupid (a casual reader reads the book and throws it down in disgust), you've already done well enough to avoid that. If you want it to hold up to some pedantic expert climatologist, then nothing short of modeling it with a proper simulation will work. But I don't know of any software that will do that for you off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilt you are considering is not that far of from earth's tilt , which is about 23 degrees, so maybe the best option is to consider  that its a earth like planet and that includes about the same size, cause the planet size have impact on climate. As for the climate watch artifexian YouTube video realistic climate:
https://youtu.be/5lCbxMZJ4zA
https://youtu.be/fag48Nh8PXE